# Is thread sleeping in while(true) loop a bad way to reduce cpu usage?

Tags: c#, multithreading, sleep

I have dropped my cpu % back to almost 0. But the code just feels so dirty.
Is there a better alternative to while(true) with a delay to drop cpu time?

Most suggestions for c# and java seems to be to just do it like this.

[What is the effect of having an empty while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11809277/what-is-the-effect-of-having-an-empty-while-loop)

Comment: Instead of doing your work on a dedicated thread, consider making it a scheduled task instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Alexander. The thing is that I need a pretty high data polling rate, would it still be viable to schedule tasks instead?

Comment: I'm not a .NET guy, so I saw that I used confusing terminology (ScheduledTask meaning something else in .NET). I meant that you should schedule the running of your work method. There is a "ElapsedEventHandler" functionality in .NET which seems to do what I suggested, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/17889407/83741.

Comment: Thanks for your input Alexander :)

Comment: No problem. Could you use it?

Comment: I have not been able to get back to this project this week. I will test it next week. Will give you an update then :)